# Как создать Adapter с неограниченным количеством строк и с неограниченным разным количеством столбцов в каждой строке

Tags: java, android

Как создать Adapter с неограниченным количеством строк и с неограниченным разным количеством столбцов в каждой строке

Comment: Насколько большое "неограниченное" вам нужно? Сотни, миллионы, триллионы?

Comment: ~ 1500 строк и ~50-60 столбцов

Comment: Приветствую, слово идет об ~1000 строк и ~50 столбов

Comment: Вопрос все равно непонятен. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/581088/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE